# How to find modulo of negative floating point number?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm studying Hill Cipher and I tried to calculate the key.
[here's the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Zss.png)

The problem is I get -ve floating point numbers.
How can I get the mod 26 of them?

For example, what's the value of (-11/121) mod 26?

Comment: This cipher is meant for integers. You can't "generalize" it to floats.

Comment: yes but when I tried to find the key K where K = C * P^-1 I get a negative floats elements in the matrix!

Comment: No, the matrix division is made modulo $26$ and yields integers, as shown in the example.

Comment: ok I calculated by hand C * P^-1 and I get the following matrix

[ [-11/121, 110/121], [37/121, 103/121]]  How would I get the mod 26 of this matrix?

Comment: You didn't perform the computation modulo $26$, but using ordinary arithmetic.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand it. When I calculate the inverse of [ [5, 8], [17 3] ] How I get the (1/determinant) mod 26?

Comment: Search here on [modular inverse Bezout](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=modular%20inverse%20bezout)